# How to disable Material Slider Widget

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-components-android, android-slider

I'm using Slider Widget from google Material library and I need to prevent user from slide the widget for a while. Is there any way to do that? (I prefer to not using `onPositionChanged()` method)

```xml
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/speakerVolumeBottomSheetSeekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/SliderMaterialTheme"
        app:labelBehavior="gone"
        android:value="0.5"
        app:thumbColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:trackColorActive="@color/colorAccent"
        app:trackColorInactive="@color/white_22_opacity" />
```

Comment: Did you tried something obvious like property called oposite to "disabled" ?

Comment: @Selvin Yeah, I tried that, and that did not work for me.

Comment: It works ... so the problem is your other code ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
   <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:enabled="false"/>
```

or programmatically:

```
slider.isEnabled = false
```